# Numpy assignment like 'numpy.take'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Is it possible to assign to a numpy array along the lines of how the `take` functionality works?

E.g. if I have an array `a`, a list of indices `inds`, and a desired axis, I can use `take` as follows:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(12).reshape((3, -1))
inds = np.array([1, 2])
print(np.take(a, inds, axis=1))

[[ 1  2]
 [ 5  6]
 [ 9 10]]
```

This is extremely useful when the indices / axis needed may change at runtime.

However, numpy does not let you do this:

```
np.take(a, inds, axis=1) = 0
print(a)
```

It looks like there is some limited (1-D) support for this via `numpy.put`, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: How about `a[:,inds] = 0`?

Comment: the point is that I want to be able to do `a[inds, :] = 0`, or `a[:, inds] = 0` or (in the 3-D case) `a[:, :, inds] = 0`, etc. programmatically, without writing a bunch of if statements

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
In [222]: a = np.arange(12).reshape((3, -1))
     ...: inds = np.array([1, 2])
     ...: 
In [223]: np.take(a, inds, axis=1)
Out[223]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 9, 10]])
In [225]: a[:,inds]
Out[225]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 9, 10]])
```

construct an indexing tuple

```
In [226]: idx=[slice(None)]*a.ndim
In [227]: axis=1
In [228]: idx[axis]=inds
In [229]: a[tuple(idx)]
Out[229]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 9, 10]])
In [230]: a[tuple(idx)] = 0
In [231]: a
Out[231]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  3],
       [ 4,  0,  0,  7],
       [ 8,  0,  0, 11]])
```

Or for `a[inds,:]`:

```
In [232]: idx=[slice(None)]*a.ndim
In [233]: idx[0]=inds
In [234]: a[tuple(idx)]
Out[234]: 
array([[ 4,  0,  0,  7],
       [ 8,  0,  0, 11]])
In [235]: a[tuple(idx)]=1
In [236]: a
Out[236]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

### PP's suggestion:

```
def put_at(inds, axis=-1, slc=(slice(None),)): 
    return (axis<0)*(Ellipsis,) + axis*slc + (inds,) + (-1-axis)*slc
```

To be used as in `a[put_at(ind_list,axis=axis)]`

I've seen both styles on `numpy` functions.  This looks like one used for `extend_dims`, mine was used in `apply_along/over_axis`.

### earlier thoughts

In a recent `take` question I/we figured out that it was equivalent to `arr.flat[ind]` for some some raveled index.  I'll have to look that up.

There is an `np.put` that is equivalent to assignment to the `flat`:

```
Signature: np.put(a, ind, v, mode='raise')
Docstring:
Replaces specified elements of an array with given values.

The indexing works on the flattened target array. `put` is roughly
equivalent to:

    a.flat[ind] = v
```

Its docs also mention `place` and `putmask` (and `copyto`).

[numpy multidimensional indexing and the function 'take'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573568/numpy-multidimensional-indexing-and-the-function-take)

I commented `take` (without axis) is equivalent to:

```
lut.flat[np.ravel_multi_index(arr.T, lut.shape)].T
```

with `ravel`:

```
In [257]: a = np.arange(12).reshape((3, -1))
In [258]: IJ=np.ix_(np.arange(a.shape[0]), inds)
In [259]: np.ravel_multi_index(IJ, a.shape)
Out[259]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 9, 10]], dtype=int32)
In [260]: np.take(a,np.ravel_multi_index(IJ, a.shape))
Out[260]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 9, 10]])
In [261]: a.flat[np.ravel_multi_index(IJ, a.shape)] = 100
In [262]: a
Out[262]: 
array([[  0, 100, 100,   3],
       [  4, 100, 100,   7],
       [  8, 100, 100,  11]])
```

and to use `put`:

```
In [264]: np.put(a, np.ravel_multi_index(IJ, a.shape), np.arange(1,7))
In [265]: a
Out[265]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  3,  4,  7],
       [ 8,  5,  6, 11]])
```

Use of `ravel` is unecessary in this case but might useful in others.

Comment: You seem to be overlooking the use of the `axis` argument.

Comment: Thanks! It'd be nice if `put` had similar functionality to take with respect to the axis argument, but the construction of the indexing tuple works for me

Comment: Here is a convenience function for index construction which doesn't need to know the array's ndim: `def put_at(inds, axis=-1, slc=(slice(None),)): return (axis<0)*(Ellipsis,) + axis*slc + (inds,) + (-1-axis)*slc` To be used as in `a[put_at(ind_list,axis=axis)]`. @hpaulj feel free to add this to your post if it passes muster.

Answer (score 0):

I have given an example for use of
[numpy.take in 2 dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573568/numpy-multidimensional-indexing-and-the-function-take/45288724#45288724/%22numpy.take%20in%202%20dimensions%22). Perhaps you can adapt that to your problem

Answer (score -1):

You can juste use indexing in this way :

```
a[:,[1,2]]=0
```