# Numpy: Performing in-place operation along moving axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Ok I did my best to describe my problem in the title.

My problem is as follows:

I have a numpy array which may not always have a consistent shape/dimension (ranges from 1 to 3). Taking the simplest case when the array is of shape [100], I can perform the following (and obtain the desired result):

```
for i, bounds in enumerate(values):
    low, high = bounds
    arr[i] *= high - low
```

when the array is of shape [100, 200], I can do the following:

```
for i, bounds in enumerate(values):
    low, high = bounds
    arr[i, :] *= high - low
```

or if the array is of shape [200, 100], I can instead do:

```
for i, bounds in enumerate(values):
    low, high = bounds
    arr[:, i] *= high - low
```

and in the 3d case if the array is of shape [300, 100, 200], I would do:

```
for i, bounds in enumerate(values):
    low, high = bounds
    arr[:, i, :] *= high - low
```

My problem is I don't know how to alter the position of `i` in the index or how to index all the elements when iterating over the axis that corresponds to `i` (when the shape of `arr` is changing). In my example, the "location" of `i` is based on where `100` falls in the shape of the array. Is this something numpy can do or am I stuck with a number of if statements?

Comment: What if it's `[100,100]`? How would you know whether it's case 1 or 2?

Comment: @Barmar If you have any ideas for handling that I'd be interested but for now I merely perform a check to ensure that there are NO duplicates in the shape (because you are correct - my logic is entirely shot at that point... good news is I don't anticipate that happening for my situation). I suppose I could have a separate list that tracks the axes of the arr when manipulated

Comment: looks like you want a 'put' equivalent of `np.take` (which takes an axis parameter).  I explored this 5 years ago in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42656930/numpy-assignment-like-numpy-take

Comment: numpy is usually easier if you can work with a consistent number of dimensions, or maybe just a few.  And if the axis of interest is in a consistent position, either first or last.  Arrays can be preprocessed, using reshape to add dimensions, and swap/transpose to move axes.  Done right these are views,  Some functions like `inv` require a (...,n,n)` shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the indexes dynamically. The set of indexes is a tuple, and `:` is `slice(None)`.

Find the index in the dimensions that's the same as the length of values. Then update that index in the list of index list in the loop.

```
indexes = [slice(None)] * arr.ndims
variable_pos = arr.shape.index(len(values))
for i, (low, high) in enumerate(values):
    indexes[variable_pos] = i
    arr[tuple(indexes)] *= high - low
```

Comment: Well there is the potential for more than 4 cases, I was just creating examples. There would be the case of `[i]`, [`:, i]`, `[i, :]`, `[i, :, :]`, `[:, i, :]`, `[:, :, i]` to be precise. So I guess only 2 more cases but this is pretty ugly and not "numpythonic"

Comment: Well, the index is a tuple, and `:` is `slice()`. So you can create these dynamically. I'm not sure what a good way to substitute `i` into the variable position is, though.

Comment: mmm knowing that `:` is `slice()` might actually help me. Running out of time today though

Comment: I was just about to post a nearly identical answer. The only difference between yours and mine is that I have `variable_pos = arr.shape.index(len(values))`.

Comment: Of course that's right.

Comment: Oh, and I used `np.s_[:]` instead of `slice(None)`. I'm not sure why NumPy's slice returns `slice(None, None, None)` instead of the single `None`.

Comment: They're equivalent. `None` is the default value for each of the parameters, and `__str__()` shows all of them.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to move the axis to put the axis you want (according to your criterion) first, in a new view `a2`. Then `a2[i,:,:]` is the same as `arr[:,i,:]` (for example) if the correct axis was 1. Plus, that way, you can use `...` notation, to replace all the `:`. So `a2[i,...]`.

```py
# Move axis whose size is 100 in 1st position (index 0) in a2 view
# (a2 is a view of arr. So modifying its contents change arr content).
# Note, if the 1st axis is already of size 100 this will do nothing
a2 = np.moveaxis(arr, arr.shape.index(100), 0) 

for i, (low, high) in enumerate(values):
    a2[i, ...] *= high - low
    # Note this `...` works whatever the dimension, even 1.
```